# Dynamics Ax 2009: create view using UNION and tables with this same fields name

Tags: sql, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I want to create a view in `dynamics ax 2009`, this view has to return two or more tables with this same fields name.

I prepare the sql query (query is below), but I don't known how to move these scripts into the `ax` view.

```
select invent.ASSETID, invent.ITEMID, invent.JOURNALID as 'ids'
    from inventjournaltrans invent
    where invent.ASSETID != ''

UNION

select purch.ASSETID, purch.ITEMID, purch.PURCHID as 'ids'
    from purchline purch
    where purch.ASSETID != ''
```

Comment: Did you take a look at [View Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc634339(v=ax.50).aspx) and [How to: Combine Data Sources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc605991(v=ax.50).aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Please find below sample of x++ query. But you must bear in mind that in standard AX fields PurchId and JournalId have different lengths, and you will get the following error:

> There is a field mismatch in the union query. Field JournalId is not compatible with field PurchId.

```
Query                 query;
QueryBuildDataSource  qbdsInventJournalTrans;
QueryBuildDataSource  qbdsPurchLine;
QueryBuildRange       qbrInventJournalTrans;
QueryBuildRange       qbrPurchLine;
;

query = new Query();
query.queryType(QueryType::Union);

qbdsInventJournalTrans = query.addDataSource(tableNum(InventJournalTrans));
qbdsInventJournalTrans.unionType(UnionType::UnionAll); // Include duplicate records
qbdsInventJournalTrans.fields().dynamic(false);
qbdsInventJournalTrans.fields().clearFieldList();
qbdsInventJournalTrans.fields().addField(fieldNum(InventJournalTrans, AssetId));
qbdsInventJournalTrans.fields().addField(fieldNum(InventJournalTrans, ItemId));
//qbdsInventJournalTrans.fields().addField(fieldNum(InventJournalTrans, JournalId));

qbrInventJournalTrans = qbdsInventJournalTrans.addRange(fieldNum(InventJournalTrans, AssetId));
qbrInventJournalTrans.value(SysQuery::valueNotEmptyString());

qbdsPurchLine = query.addDataSource(tableNum(PurchLine));
qbdsPurchLine.unionType(UnionType::UnionAll); // Include duplicate records
qbdsPurchLine.fields().dynamic(false);
qbdsPurchLine.fields().clearFieldList();
qbdsPurchLine.fields().addField(fieldNum(PurchLine, AssetId));
qbdsPurchLine.fields().addField(fieldNum(PurchLine, ItemId));
//qbdsPurchLine.fields().addField(fieldNum(PurchLine, PurchId));

qbrPurchLine = qbdsPurchLine.addRange(fieldNum(PurchLine, AssetId));
qbrPurchLine.value(SysQuery::valueNotEmptyString());
```

Please refer this link if you need to create AOT query [How to: Combine Data Sources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc605991(v=ax.50).aspx)